# iphone : message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

i know that kind of noob problem but it killing me for 2 days now
i have the following code

```
albumsVC.discList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(id song in songs){
    if([self checkIfAllFilesExist:[song objectForKey:@"fileName"]]){ 
        [albumsVC.discList addObject:song];
    }
}
```

and

```
 -(BOOL)checkIfAllFilesExist: (NSString *) theFilename {
    BOOL exist;
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    docPath = [ documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3",theFilename]];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    exist = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:docPath];
    docPath = nil;
    docPath = [[NSString alloc] init];
    if(!exist){
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

but it crashes after five loops (i don't know why five ? ) and it tells me that message sent to deallocated instance 0x87cdc10 
on the line of

```
docPath = [ documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3",theFilename]];
```

where docPath is NSString in the header created as nonatomic and retain ..

i can't get the problem can you help me ?

Comment: First of all improve your accep rate, nobody is going to answer you with a 66%

Comment: Product > Edit Scheme... > Run > Enable Zombie Objects might give you more clues to the cause of the problem. Have you tried it?

Comment: did you try to use instruments ? its very useful for this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

`-(BOOL)checkIfAllFilesExist: (NSString *) theFilename` creates memory leak.

Replace it with below code:

```
-(BOOL)checkIfAllFilesExist: (NSString *) theFilename {
    BOOL exist;
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    self.docPath = [ documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3",theFilename]];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    exist = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:docPath];
    if(!exist){
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Assuming that you have docPath property in your .h file with nonatomic, retain.

Answer (score 0):

since you say it is always crashes at the fifth iteration of the loop, check the bject which comes by looping.

I mean to say , check the `theFilename`. Try printing the `'song'` dictionary to make sure you have something in `fileName` key.

Also use Apurv code.

Comment: when i nslog the song it gives me on the fifth element 2012-04-02 11:40:34.880 AWahab[2937:17603] *** -[CFString isNSString__]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x87a7d10

Comment: I asked you to add Apurv code since it is cleaner than you have now. As you mentioned the song is deallocated. That's why you get this error. Check where you create the array of dictionary.

Comment: i actually found why it's happen on the fifth row it's because i do this on the rowdidselect for tableview .. the fifth row is the last row.. for ipad it crash on the 13 row.. weird i know